# How do I call functions of an object inside the same object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following Javascript code

```
add_num = {
  f: function(html, num) {
    alert(this.page);
  },

  page : function() {
    return parseInt(this.gup('page'));
  },

  gup : function(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,'\\\[').replace(/[\]]/,'\\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]'+name+'=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
      return '';
    else
      return results[1];
  }
}
```

But when I call add_num.f() what I get from alert() is the actual code of page. That is, it returns

```
function() {
    return parseInt(this.gup('page'));
  }
```

I was expecting a numeric value and not any code at all.

Comment: You are not actually *calling* the function - just passing it as an object to `alert()`. Try `alert(this.page());`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you need to call the `page` function:

```
alert(this.page());
```

instead of

```
alert(this.page);
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that a literal is not a function, thus has no (visible) constructor so 'this' is going to refer to the calling object.

Of course, this is not true if you use assign this literal to the prototype of a function, but i am guessing this is not the case here.

Also, Darin is correct, you are returning the function, not executing it.

Just refer to the object explicitly, e.g. add_num.page().

```
add_num = {
  f: function(html, num) {
    alert(add_num.page());
  },

  page : function() {
    return parseInt(add_num.gup('page'));
  },

  gup : function(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,'\\\[').replace(/[\]]/,'\\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]'+name+'=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
      return '';
    else
      return results[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it bad practice to use `this` over calling the object explicitly?

Answer (score 4):

You are alerting the function itself, not the result of executing it.
You should do this:

```
alert(this.page());
```